# Null Pointer Creating SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite, nullpointerexception

Why do these two lines of code throw a NPE?

```
SQLiteDatabase db;
db = openOrCreateDatabase("TestingData.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
```

Stacktrace:

```
08-23 10:33:14.285: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1001): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-23 10:33:14.285: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
08-23 10:33:14.285: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at org.*****.android.CopyOfSQLLite.data(CopyOfSQLLite.java:14)
08-23 10:33:14.285: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at org.******.android.*****.****(****.java:200)
08-23 10:33:14.285: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at org.********.android.****.onCreate(DashboardPage.java:25)
08-23 10:33:14.285: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-23 10:33:14.285: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
```

Comment: are you sure error is coming exactly here?

Comment: And why are you using the method with 3 parameters if you set the last one to null? There is also a method that only expects to parameters. (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/såqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ContextWrapper does not have a base Context. Most likely you are not calling this method at the correct place, but I cannot say more without a little more code.

Answer (score 0):

The nice thing about Android is that it is [open source](http://hi-android.info/src/android/content/ContextWrapper.java.html).  So we can see that `openOrCreateDatabase()` is implemented like:

```
public SQLiteDatabase openOrCreateDatabase(String name, int mode, CursorFactory factory) {
    return mBase.openOrCreateDatabase(name, mode, factory);
}
```

The only way I can see this code throwing a NPE is if `mBase` is null.  From your calling convention I assume your class is derived from `android.content.ContextWrapper`?  If so, are you ensuring that the base context (`mBase`) is set when your class is instantiated?  If you aren't, then that would be what's causing the problem.