# NullPointerException in android project

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-intent, android-activity

I tried to launch AddEditRecipesActivity.java from RecipesActivity.java. In RecipesActivity there is a list of data from datatable. By pressing Add button in RecipesActivity, AddEditRecipesActivity.java is called, where I insert data in datatable. But when I pressed this button, my application crashed.

This is LogCat messages.

```
08-20 04:13:20.315: E/Your TAG,(9425): Your Message
-    08-20 04:13:20.315: E/Your TAG,(9425): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.behealthy/com.example.behealthy.AddEditRecipesActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
-    08-20 04:13:20.315: E/Your TAG,(9425):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2024)
-    08-20 04:13:20.315: E/Your TAG,(9425):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
-    08-20 04:13:20.315: E/Your TAG,(9425):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
-    08-20 04:13:20.315: E/Your TAG,(9425):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
-    08-20 04:13:20.315: E/Your TAG,(9425):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
-    08-20 04:13:20.315: E/Your TAG,(9425):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
-    08-20 04:13:20.315: E/Your TAG,(9425):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
-    08-20 04:13:20.315: E/Your TAG,(9425):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
-    08-20 04:13:20.315: E/Your TAG,(9425):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
-    08-20 04:13:20.315: E/Your TAG,(9425):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
-    08-20 04:13:20.315: E/Your TAG,(9425):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
-    08-20 04:13:20.315: E/Your TAG,(9425):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
-    08-20 04:13:20.315: E/Your TAG,(9425): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
-    08-20 04:13:20.315: E/Your TAG,(9425):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:228)
-    08-20 04:13:20.315: E/Your TAG,(9425):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
-    08-20 04:13:20.315: E/Your TAG,(9425):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
-    08-20 04:13:20.315: E/Your TAG,(9425):     at com.example.behealthy.AddEditRecipesActivity.<init>(AddEditRecipesActivity.java:27)
-    08-20 04:13:20.315: E/Your TAG,(9425):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
-    08-20 04:13:20.315: E/Your TAG,(9425):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
-    08-20 04:13:20.315: E/Your TAG,(9425):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1057)
-    08-20 04:13:20.315: E/Your TAG,(9425):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2015)
-    08-20 04:13:20.315: E/Your TAG,(9425):     ... 11 more
```

Thanks.

Comment: Well, something that you're trying to use is null. Find out what, then [why](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7159853/645270). (The "what" part is easy, you get a line number in the logcat). My link is only a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this line

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

we know that the problem is that something is `null`. And from this line (the first line after that references your project)

```
at com.example.behealthy.AddEditRecipesActivity.<init>(AddEditRecipesActivity.java:27)
```

we know that the "something that is null" is at line 27 of `AddEditRecipesActivity`

See what could be `null` there and figure out why it would be `null`. If you need more help then please post the relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

A variable that you are accessing in `AddEditRecipesActivity` at line 27 is `null`.

If you double-click a message in the logcat, eclipse will take you to the relevant line.

If you cannot see which variable is `null` try printing some values with

```
Log.d("MyTag", "The value of xyz="+xyz);
```

Or run your code under the debugger.

Comment: This should be a comment... not answer

Comment: @Sushil flag it if you feel strongly. My feeling of the OP was that this kind of guidance was needed, as also shown by codeMagic's answer.

Comment: This is debateable, as is mine I suppose, but if they know how to see the logcat then teaching them what it means and how to use it is a good answer in my opinion. I would suggest in the future to explain how you got to your conclusion though. +1 though for the double-click...I use it but often forget to mention it

Comment: @codeMagic thanks for the advice ... still learning what makes a good online answer!

Comment: You're welcome. Just always do your best to explain WHY the solution works. And remember, code is good but explanation is better. I have learned a lot from some of the great contributors on here...pragnani, RaghavSood, commonsware, blackbelt, prosperK, raghundan (completely wrong), and many others